# How to find difference of two sum's result by onKeyUp()?

Tags: android

[enter image description here][1]I have eight EditText, five for Income & three for deduction and I have set a `TextWatcher` at all EditText by calling addTextChangedListener().

Now I have set the sum of first five EditText to TextView(value) and sum of other three EditText to TextView(ded_value). As whichever EditText is going to fill likewise sum is setting on respective TextView.

These TextView are showing the only total earning & total deduction and now I m am trying to set the net payable salary which will be difference of value,ded_value(means total earning-total deduction=net payable salary).

And the result of this defference should be diaplay on another TextView that is netsalaryvalue. As whichever(value,ded_value) TextView is going to changing likewise difference should be set on TextView(netsalaryvalue).

```
enter code here   //this is income salry & deduction salary code
    textWatcher=new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            //income code value
            b_salary=et_bs.getText().toString();
            d_allowance=et_da.getText().toString();
            hr_allowance=et_hra.getText().toString();
            t_allowance=et_ta.getText().toString();
            m_allowance=et_ma.getText().toString();

            //deduction code value
            itax=et_itax.getText().toString();
            pf=et_pf.getText().toString();
            tds=et_tds.getText().toString();

            if (!et_bs.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                value.setText("");
                value.setText(b_salary);
            if (!et_da.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                value.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(b_salary)+Integer.parseInt(d_allowance)));
                if (!et_hra.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    value.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(b_salary)+Integer.parseInt(d_allowance)+Integer.parseInt(hr_allowance)));
                    if (!et_ta.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    {
                        value.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(b_salary)+Integer.parseInt(d_allowance)+Integer.parseInt(hr_allowance)+Integer.parseInt(t_allowance)));
                        if (!et_ma.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                        {
                            value.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(b_salary)+Integer.parseInt(d_allowance)+Integer.parseInt(hr_allowance)+Integer.parseInt(t_allowance)+Integer.parseInt(m_allowance)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            }

            if (!et_itax.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                ded_value.setText("");
                ded_value.setText(itax);
                if (!et_pf.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    ded_value.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(itax)+Integer.parseInt(pf)));
                    if (!et_tds.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    {
                        ded_value.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(itax)+Integer.parseInt(pf)+Integer.parseInt(tds)));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    };
    et_bs.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    et_da.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    et_hra.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    et_ta.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    et_ma.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    et_itax.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    et_pf.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    et_tds.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    // this is net payable salry code
    textWatcher2=new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            netsalaryvalue.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            totalincome=value.getText().toString();
            totaldedu=ded_value.getText().toString();

                if (!value.getText().toString().equals("")||!ded_value.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    if (!value.getText().toString().equals("00.00")||!ded_value.getText().toString().equals("00.00"))
                    {
                        netsalaryvalue.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(totalincome)-Integer.parseInt(totaldedu)));
                    }
                }
        }
    };

    value.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher2);
    ded_value.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher2);
```

**strong text** When I was finding only the sum then my code was running freely  but when I had write the code for netpayablesalry then my app is going to crash. Now I m trying to resolve this issue but still now issue is not resolve, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
textWatcher=new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        value.setText("");


    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        basic=et_bs.getText().toString();
        allowance=et_da.getText().toString();
        if(!basic.isEmpty() && !allowance.isEmpty())
             value.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(basic)+Integer.parseInt(allowance)));

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

you can also add these three lines in onAfterTextChanged

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   basic=et_bs.getText().toString();
   allowance=et_da.getText().toString();
   if(!basic.isEmpty() && !allowance.isEmpty())
       value.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(basic)+Integer.parseInt(allowance)));
}
```

Comment: This is not working sir, when I start to type then app is going to crash

Comment: what is the exception? I have also updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
 @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
   int before, int count) {
     basic=et_bs.getText().toString();
     allowance=et_da.getText().toString();
     ////Check for null/empty/Not-Integer value
     int first = 0;
     int second = 0;
     try {
      first = Integer.parseInt(basic);
      second = Integer.parseInt(allowance);
      }
      catch(Exception e ) {
     }
       value.setText(""+String.valueOf(first+second)));
    }
```

Comment: Thank sir, your code help me but not 100% but now I can make it 100%. Thanks again

Comment: What you mean by 100% ?

Comment: Means, I m trying that when I have input first value then first value should be print on textview, but by your code first was not printing when I have input. result was displaying when I enter the value int second edittext.

Answer (score 0):

**strong text** According to my question exact answer is:-

```
enter code here   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            basic=et_bs.getText().toString();
            allowance=et_da.getText().toString();
            value.setText(basic);
            if (!et_da.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                value.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(basic)+Integer.parseInt(allowance)));
            }

        }
```

**strong text** now it is working which was I trying.

Comment: also set default values to 0 for et_bs and et_da